# Call VBA method every time Excel cell is updated

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a trading algorithm in Excel and VBA. A cell in the Excel document gets updated from a trader client with the time remaining. I want to call a method every time that cell changes its value. How is this done?

Comment: you can take a look at Siddharth Rout's solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441286/need-a-macro-to-detect-if-cell-value-changes-from-current-value   and use the `Worksheet_Change` part.

Comment: There has to be a simpler way. Are there nothing I can write in the excel document to call a method on cell change state?

Comment: @user17170: simpler ? I can't see what can be simpler than Larry's suggestion.

Comment: You have to write VBA to achieve the even triggering that you require. Cells can only call a VBA `Function` and Excel is designed to not allow a `Function` to edit the state of a workbook

Comment: Calling `functions` and `cell_change events` please take care of your sheet from going into infinite loops.. `Application.EnableEvents` can  ensure the macro/function triggered by cell change does NOT cause the change event to run again and get itself in a loop...

Comment: agree with @bonCodigo. You might also want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640

Comment: @SiddharthRout I remember clearly when you pointed that out the last time :) thanks mate.

Comment: couldn't search this post, wanted to :(

Answer (score 1):

See the solution on this page:

[automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

To trigger an event when cell A1 changes,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Macro
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for `Worksheet_Change` However may I take this opportunity to draw your attention towards this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640