# Initiate SQL insert by user from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, excel-2013, vba

Not sure if this question is suitable in stackoverflow or should be in superuser, but I'm trying to create an excel sheet which allows users to make a comment/note to their sales figures. I then need to collect all the notes and comments to a SQL table, then output in a report that would consolidate all the notes from users and output for managers.

The part I'm struggling is how to INSERT the user comment/note from excel to a SQL table. I thought about scheduling using SSIS, but because users could be working on the excel often, and many managers want to have a real time data, I cannot use schedule method.

The only way this would work is if the INSERT was initiated right from excel by the user.

Ideally, the user would type in the comment in the table, and click on macro button that would initiate a SQL INSERT/Update query.

Is this all possible?

I have Office 2013 SP and SQL is SQL 2012 11.0.3381

Comment: Create a button that runs the insert in a macro. Do you have any experience with VBA? What 'key' will you be able to use to record your comment - i.e. in a given sales report a salesperson and a month combined might be something that you use to make a unique comment. What does the existing table look like? What you ask for is definitely possible but we'll need lots more information before a solution can be suggested. What are you developing your final report in?

Comment: I have almost 0 experience with VBA. At least none that I created from 0 without relying on recording. The current table includes month, account name, current sales, and Quota. I'm thinking I could create a column that concatenates month and account name that I could use as the key.

Comment: You don't need to do any concatenaing, you just need to identify what will uniquely identify a comment. So the Month and Account name will also exist on the Excel sheet? Next questions are: 1. Have you considered security - i.e. is it important to stop someone modifying someone elses comment? 2. Do you have a method to connect to the database? do you have an existing SQL Server Login/PWD to connect? Who owns this database and can they assist with these technical questions? Basically the VBA code needs to connect to the database and run a statement based off some cells in your worksheet.

Comment: I have both Month and account in the excel sheet, sales are supposed to add/update comment for sales figure by account by month. I have existing SQL on the server, and I already have a table set up, but I'm not sure of the way to initiate SQL INSERT query right from Excel.

Comment: To do an insert you first write VBA code to connect to the database, then write VBA code to execute an INSERT/UPDATE. You also need to consider that the user will need to see any existing comment on the sheet. The first step is to get a working connection string. Follow these instructions to get a connection string: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhejo_vanissery/archive/2007/09/07/one-minute-connection-string.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
[Need a macro to detect if cell value changes from current value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441286/need-a-macro-to-detect-if-cell-value-changes-from-current-value)

However, I have an idea for you. What about... instead of having these comments on an Excel Spreadsheet, you code an online version of the same worksheet? Then you will have AJAX on your side to trigger the creation of all these reports seamlessly.
e.g., https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/spreadsheet/

If the cultural shock within the company is too big, you can set-up a windows scheduled task to run a little program that parses the spreadsheet and populates the online version, then they will co-exist and you can start marketing the benefits of the new approach.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. What do you mean by the online version of the same worksheet? The excel is posted on SharePoint for users to go in and make the update.

Comment: Something like this: http://handsontable.com/ -- "This is a new version 0.10.3. It introduces more plugin hooks (for Events and Callbacks)...". Then you will have control over the changes on specific cells.

Comment: Hm, I wish I could leverage something like this, but the current excel pulls sales data from SQL, I wouldn't have web coding knowledge to mimic it in web interface..

Comment: Dude, collaboration! Pull in a developer to work with you on this (You can even leverage the mechanism that is currently populating the spreadsheet and see if you can develop some add-on on top of the same functionality to detect changes and run your desired stored procs to generate the reports.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a cute solution, but you can click a button to invoke exp/imp wizard and modify the query to update the SQL Server table.